# Store AWS IoT data and request real-time and bulk data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

Currently i'm working on a project where i have 7 of the same sensors (temperature, light, movement) in the AWS IoT. These sensors are placed in different rooms of the building. These sensors send an update every 5 minutes.

I need a secure way to store the data in AWS and get this to an external customer.
To showcase this i want do create a dashboard showing a floor map of the building with following features:

- Get latest data of each sensor
- Show the temperature on the correct place on the image
- Update the data in realtime when an update of the sensor happened
- Show a graph and all data of a selected sensor

I currently saved the data of all the sensors in 1 DynamoDB Table and created a working API in this manner:

```
API Gateway -> AWS Lambda -> DynamoDB <- AWS IoT <- Sensors
```

But problems with this are the fact that it does not update realtime. And it is hard to only get the latest value out of DynamoDB. So i need a better way.

2 questions:

- What is the best way to store the data in AWS for this purpose? And how to create a userfriendly and secured API to request realtime and bulk data?
- Does there exist a dashboard tool that can show sensor data on a static image?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store your data in AWS depends in a large part on how you want to access the data. From the use case you have described Dynamodb will work along with a web socket connection to the AWS IOT MQTT message broker.

For Dynamodb I would consider creating a table with a partion key that is your sensor id, and a sort key that is the timestamp. Then you can easily query the table to get the newest records for each sensor. Set the ScanIndexForward parameter to false to return the record in descending order in the query.

For Realtime messages you can connect to the AWS IOT MQTT message broker from your browser using a MQTT over web sockets. You can subscribe to the same topics that your sensors publish to and receive realtime updates.